# Line of intersection/quadric surfaces

Tags: multivariable-calculus, plane-curves, quadrics

Let $C$ be the curve of intersection of the cylinder $\frac{x^2}{25}$ + $\frac{y^2}{9}$ = $1$ with the plane $3z = 4y$. Let $L$ be the line tangent to $C$ at the point $(0,-3,-4)$. What is the x-coordinate of the point of intersection of L and the plane $2x - 3y - 4z = 27$ ?

Don't even know where to begin this problem. Have a very shaky understanding of quadric surfaces. Can somebody walk me through this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x=5\cos t,y=3\sin t$ then $z=4\sin t$ and so
 $$r(t)=(5\cos t,3\sin t,4\sin t)\implies t=3\pi/2\iff r=(0,-3,-4)
\\ r'(t)=(-5\sin t,3\cos t,4\cos t)
$$ the parallel to the line is $u=(5,0,0)$ and the equatio of $L$ is $r_1(t)=(0,-3,-4)+t(5,0,0)\implies x=5t,y=-3,z=-4 $. Finally the point of intersection is
$$2(5t)-3(-3)-4(-4)=27\implies t=1/5\implies point=(1,-3,-4)$$

Comment: how'd you decide that t = $3pi/2$?

Comment: $5\cos t=0,3\sin t=-3, 4 \sin t=-4$

Comment: and how'd you come up with the parallel to the line is (5,0,0)?

Comment: since $L$ is the tangent line, the tangent vector $r'$ to $C$ is parallel to the line $L$ at that point so i plug $3\pi/2$ in $r'$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**.  Parametrise the curve - write $x$ and $y$ in terms of trig functions of $t$ to make sure the point lies on the cylinder, then find $z$ in terms of $t$ to make the point lie on the plane too.  This gives a parametrisation of the curve
$${\bf r}(t)=(x(t),y(t),z(t))\ .$$
A tangent to the curve is given by the derivative ${\bf r}'(t)$.  This gives you an equation for $L$ in terms of $t$, substitute into the equation of the plane, find $t$ etc.  Good luck!

Comment: how do we know to parametrise the equation? And what's the process to determine which trig functions to use?

Comment: **Hint**.  Although it is a $3$-dimensional problem, the equation $x^2/25+y^2/9=1$ should remind you of a familiar $2$-dimensional curve.  Use the same parametrisation.